# Please provide the astrological remedy for the ascendant chakra given below-

Tags: astrology

[image]

What is the astrological remedy for this ascendent chakra? (Please explain in depth)

Comment: Your question is WAYYY too broad. Remedy for what exactly?

Comment:  You can provide neccessary remedies according to you

Comment: Again, it is too broad, not to mention, there's many details missing. It's only possible to guess the issue based on just the Kshetra Chakra that you've provided. For pinpointing of potential problems, Navamsha and other Vargas are needed. Not to mention, what Ayanamsha has been used here? What Dasha are you running? What problems are popping up? The only thing that can be generally said is that you should do Brhaspati Stotras or Shlokas as that may cause significant issues depending on Transits, Varga Chakras, Dashas and other information.

Comment:  Date of Birth- 23-11-1988, Time - 5:15 (AM), Place- Lucknow, (Uttar Pradesh)